# MySQL Script for update another table with some calculation after updating the existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, database-administration

I have written one **MySQL Query** which is finding missing attendance from **clockInTest** table and then inserted a new row for the end time of that day. But, I also need to calculate the total office hours and break time of that days (which are newly inserted), and that I have to update the **WorkDay** table with timeSpan and breakTime. Following are the sample data I am using:

Before executing my Query:

| Id | TimeStamp | WorkDayId | EmployeeId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-26 08:00:00 | 149 | 1 | Start |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 08:00:00 | 148 | 1 | Start |
| 3 | 2021-10-26 10:00:00 | 149 | 1 | End |
| 4 | 2021-10-26 12:00:00 | 149 | 1 | Start |

After executing the following Query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO ClockInTest (PartnerId, Timestamp, WorkDayId, UserId, EmployeeId, Type )
SELECT a.PartnerId, CONCAT(DATE(a.TimeStamp),' 23:59:00'), a.WorkDayId, a.UserId, a.EmployeeId, 'End'
FROM  ClockInTest a
WHERE a.Type = 'Start' 
AND a.DeletedAt IS NULL
AND a.TIMESTAMP <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM  ClockInTest b
  WHERE b.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId
  AND a.WorkDayId = b.WorkDayId
  AND a.Timestamp < b.Timestamp
  AND b.Type = 'End'
  AND b.DeletedAt IS NULL
) GROUP BY a.WorkDayId, a.EmployeeId;
SELECT * FROM clockintest WHERE WorkDayId IN (
SELECT DISTINCT c.WorkDayId FROM clockintest c WHERE c.Id >= LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;
```

**clockInTest** table after the query execution:

| Id | TimeStamp | WorkDayId | EmployeeId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-26 08:00:00 | 149 | 1 | Start |
| 2 | 2021-10-25 08:00:00 | 148 | 1 | Start |
| 3 | 2021-10-26 10:00:00 | 149 | 1 | End |
| 4 | 2021-10-26 12:00:00 | 149 | 1 | Start |
| 5 | 2021-10-26 23:59:00 | 149 | 1 | End |
| 6 | 2021-10-25 23:59:00 | 148 | 1 | End |

So, the above table missing data are added. Now, I have to calculate the total working hours (timeSpan) and break time for each **WorkDayId** and after that, I have to update the **WorkDay** table which is like following:

**WorkDay table**

| Id | TimeSpan | EmployeeId | BreakTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 148 |  | 1 |  |
| 149 |  | 1 |  |

**Expected Result in WorkDay Table:**

| Id | TimeSpan | EmployeeId | BreakTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 148 | 57540000 | 1 | 0 |
| 149 | 50,328,000 | 1 | 7200000 |

** *TimeSpan and BreakTime in miliseconds*

Comment: Update the mistakes in the question, incorrect or incomplete SQL.  Add `CREATE TABLE` statements for any required tables.  The SQL needs to match these tables (execute without errors).  The expected results need to match the tables.  The `Id` column in `WorkDay` appears wrong.  Most importantly, the logic to derive `TimeSpan` and `BreakTime` is not provided and that's the primary goal of the question.

Comment: I'm also a little curious about the newly inserted rows of `type = 'End'` that are `24 hours - 1 minute` from the last start time of the prior day.  What is that meant to achieve?  Does that mean we're automatically inserting almost 24 hours of attendance?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the mistake. I just need one stored procedure or any way which will calculate the timespan (total working hour per day) and total break time and will enter these two values in the workday table as a Update query. @JonArmstrong

Comment: Just need to calculate the working hours and breaktime each day (from the 2nd clockInTest table) for each employee and then have to update the WorkDay table. @JonArmstrong

Comment: Again, what is `working time` and what is `break time`?  Show the exact expected result, given this specific test data.  Update your `WorkDay` table results with that exact detail.

Comment: for employee = 149, total working hour would be (10:00-8:00) + (23:59-12:00) and breakTime would be (12:00 - 10:00). and I need time in milliseconds in WorkDay table. @JonArmstrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238658/discussion-between-abhijit-mondal-abhi-and-jon-armstrong).

Comment: Update the question with that detail.  Don't forget to update the expected result, shown in the `WorkDay` table.  Also, you should include your attempted SQL.  What have you tried?  What was the result?  What did you expect (precisely)?

Comment: Updated the question with expected result in WorkDay table, @JonArmstrong

Comment: why the expected timespan is 57528000, not 57540000 for 148

Comment: You are correct. It would be  57540000 for 148. @ProGu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we can combine tables data for each `Start` type, and find the respective `End` time and the `Next Start` time if any

```
   WorkDayId | EmployeeId | Start | End | Next Start
    148 | 1 | 2021-10-25 08:00:00 | 2021-10-25 23:59:00 
    149 | 1 | 2021-10-26 08:00:00 | 2021-10-26 10:00:00 | 2021-10-26 12:00:00
    149 | 1 | 2021-10-26 12:00:00 | 2021-10-26 23:59:00 |
```

Then the expected result is simply sum up of the time diff

```
SELECT 
  a.WorkDayId, 
  a.EmployeeId, 
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.`TimeStamp`, b.`TimeStamp`)) * 1000 AS timespan,
  SUM(CASE WHEN c.`Timestamp` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, b.`TimeStamp`, c.`TimeStamp`) END) * 1000 AS breakTime
FROM clockInTest a 
JOIN clockInTest b 
  ON a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId 
     AND a.WorkDayId = b.WorkDayId 
     AND b.`Timestamp` > a.`Timestamp`
LEFT JOIN clockInTest c 
  ON a.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId 
     AND a.WorkDayId = c.WorkDayId 
     AND c.`Type` = 'Start' 
     AND c.`Timestamp` > b.`Timestamp` 
WHERE a.`Type` = 'Start'
AND b.`Type` = 'End'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM clockInTest d
  WHERE a.EmployeeId = d.EmployeeId
  AND a.WorkDayId = d.WorkDayId
  AND (
        ( d.`Timestamp` > a.`Timestamp` AND d.`Timestamp` < b.`Timestamp` )
     OR ( d.`Timestamp` > b.`Timestamp` AND d.`Timestamp` < c.`Timestamp` )
  ) 
)
GROUP BY a.WorkDayId, a.EmployeeId
ORDER BY a.WorkDayId, a.EmployeeId
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb3b1fef815f1201554fdca683a8448f

To update the results to `WorkDay` table, assume the WorkDayId & EmployeeId records exist and timespan & breakTime are empty

```
UPDATE WorkDay w
JOIN (
  ... // the above select query
) g ON w.id = g.WorkDayId AND w.EmployeeId = g.EmployeeId
SET w.TimeSpan = g.timespan, w.BreakTime = g.breakTime
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2262e5156c0a991eddbbb39ebacfd3bf

Comment: You are right. But, there is possibility for multiple start and end in the same day. So, the above SQL is capable of calculating that? And if there is only start entry in a day and someone forget to set his end time, in that case I have to set the end time (Date of the day+23:59:00). And last thing you just select the values for WorkDay table. But, I have to update the WorkDay table which already exists. That's all. @ProGu

Comment: it assumes the missing `end` records have been inserted, as you've done according to the question description. multiple start/end pairs are ok.

Comment: Absolutely working fine. Just one thing, without selecting the whole result, can you please update the WorkDay table which already exists. I have to update the TimeSpan and Breaktime in the WorkDay table for the specific Id and EmployeeId. @ProGu

Comment: @Abhijit Mondal Abhi added another update query in the answer